# Check-In post on facebook using any API call in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an android application where a user login using facebook and then click on any listed hotel and click of it. Its should allow user to post in his wall with a checkin status.

Now I am able to do facebook login part success fully. I am facing challenge how to post a checkin status on user wall how is login and once post is uploaded how to get success status.

Could anyone help me on any facebook API which help in posting checkin status on user wall.

Comment: why do you need the success status? what for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/user/feed#publish

You need to do a POST request to the /me/feed endpoint, with a Page ID for the "place" field:

> Page ID of a location associated with this post.

Of course you need to authorize users with the `publish_actions` permission for this.